# disk full -- deleting files does not work

Tags: apt, disk-usage

My hard disk is so full that I cannot even download a 2 page pdf file from the internet. This is surprising because I don't have very much on this computer (just pdfs from work). More surprising is that I get the same error even after deleting many pdf's and photos that are together much bigger than the pdf I am trying to download and emptying the trash.

I suspect that this is because I used `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` many times in rapid succession as an attempt to solve an unrelated problem. However, I have no idea what I am doing.

EDIT: `df-h`

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/sda5           15G     15G     0 100% /
none               4.0K       0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev               1.8G    4.0K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs              366M    1.3M  365M   1% /run
none               5.0M       0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none               1.8G     84K  1.8G   1% /run/shm
none               100M     24K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow           1.0M    1.0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda7           59G     70M   56G   1% /opt
/dev/sda8          118G    5.6G  106G   6% /home
/dev/sda9          261G     60M  248G   1% /u/scratch
```

Comment: Please run a `df -h` and edit the result into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install deborphan
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get clean
```